# How to add export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/bin/java) to .bashrc?

Tags: java, bash, path

I found an OSX tutorial that has me doing this to get Java to work in the terminal but it doesn't persist after that terminal is closed.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/bin/java)
```

I tried appending `/usr/bin/java` to my $PATH but it does not work, I get this error when running my library that needs Java:

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/java/bin/java" (-1)
```

Comment: Remove the `$( )` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you define JAVA_HOME in `/etc/profile` like below:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 # ---> your java path

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```